Does Size Variation Allometrically Scale with Size?
This seems like a very simple question, but I can't find any papers addressing it. Does the variation of individuals' size (height or weight) in a population scale with that population's mean size?
For example, adult male red kangaroos are usually between 1.3m and 1.6m tall. If we assume a normal distribution, then the mean height is 1.45m with a standard deviation of 0.05m. My gut says that is surprisingly little variation for an animal so tall, but is it really? Trusting your gut on statistics is an easy way to make mistakes. If I had an equation that predicted standard deviation of a population from that population's mean, I would have something to compare the male red kangaroos too, but I can't find anything like that.
If someone knows a paper that calculates this equation across species, I would be very grateful. It seems like something I could calculate myself using R, but I cannot find a database that lists the variation of height and/or weight along with the mean. If this does exist, I would be happy with that too.
P.S. Before anyone points it out, I know many species have sexual dimorphism which cause the males to be a different size than the females. That is why I talk about populations and not species until the end last paragraph. If I were to calculate the equation myself, the males and females of each species would need to be different data points or else variation would be inflated by sexual dimorphism. Otherwise, species like the anglerfish and black widow would completely ruin things.

If it didn't, then would you expect a mouse to have a SD of 0.05 m, too?

I don't know the answer, but one way you could potentially work this out is by comparing data on different human populations - take say SE Asians (shortish on a global scale)  cf. Maasai (taller on a global scale) and see if there is difference in the SD. The wikipedia page on height by country might have some good starting points

A relevant search term might be "Taylor's power law."

I stumbled upon Taylor's Power Law while trying to answer the question myself do this paper (https://pmc.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/articles/PMC3465447/). However, I do not see how it helps answer my question. It has the same mathematical form, but is about population counts, not individuals' size.
